# How to delete elements from an array that are followed by the same elements

Tags: ruby

I have an array. There are two `46`s at indices `3` and `7`:

```
arr = [7, 68, 42, 46, 9, 91, 77, 46, 86, 1]
```

I got a mission to sort this array using [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort), but not `.sort`. The result should be:

```
[1, 7, 9, 42, 46, 46, 68, 77, 86, 91]
```

So, I did this in a `.rb` file:

```
def insertion_sort(arr)
  length = arr.size
  arr.each_with_index do |number, index|
    puts "Now the index is #{index}"
    current_minimum = arr.last(length - index).min
    puts "Now the current_minimum in last#{length - index} elements is #{current_minimum}"
    arr.delete(current_minimum)
    arr.insert(index, current_minimum)
  end
end

arr =  [7, 68, 42, 46, 9, 91, 77, 46, 86, 1]
answer = insertion_sort(arr)
puts answer.to_s
```

I executed this file, then got this:

```
[1, 7, 9, 42, 68, 91, 77, 86, 46]
```

If I delete one `46`, it came out with this:

```
[1, 7, 9, 42, 46, 68, 77, 86, 91]
```

My code does not work when there are multiple occurrences of some single value in the array. When the `each_with_index` block went to index `3`, it deleted all `46`s from the rest of the array.

Could anyone tell me how to correct this?

Comment: As you found out, `delete()` removes all elements with that value. You may want `delete_at(index)` which removes only one element.

Comment: Thank you @Mark Thomas . Your answer enlightened me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To "emulate" this kind of `selection sort` you could try iterating over an array using a range starting from 0 as the value with index 0 and with the length of the array as last element. This range won't take the last array value.

Using `each` you get access to *each* value from the created range, then, using that "index", you can create a new range, again without taking the last element but this time one step ahead, that's adding 1 to the current value for `a`. This way again, using `each` you have access to `a` and `b`, from the "parent" and "child" range created before.

Now you can check if the value for the element with index `b` in the array is minor than the value for the element with index `a` in the array, if this validation is true then create a `temp` variable with the value of the element in the array with index `b`, then the element in the array at position (index) `b` will be equal to the element in the array with the position `a`, finally the element in the array at position `a`, will be equal to the `temp` variable created before.

Finally return the array passed as argument.

```
def insertion_sort(array)
  (0...array.length).each do |a|
    ((a+1)...array.size).each do |b|
      if array[b] < array[a]
        temp     = array[b]
        array[b] = array[a]
        array[a] = temp
      end
    end
  end
  array
end

arr =  [7, 68, 42, 46, 9, 91, 77, 46, 86, 1]
p insertion_sort(arr)
# => [1, 7, 9, 42, 46, 46, 68, 77, 86, 91]
```

As added @MarkThomas, you can "skip" the `temp` variable by swapping the array values with `a` and `b` indexes:

```
def insertion_sort(array)
  (0...array.length).map do |a|
    ((a+1)...array.size).each do |b|
      array[a], array[b] = array[b], array[a] if array[b] < array[a]
    end
  end
  array
end
```

Comment: Thank you! @Sebastián Palma . Great solution, and also your code looks much clearer than mine.

Comment: You don't need `temp`; you can swap using `array[a], array[b] = array[b], array[a]`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of you. I improved my code and it seems work well.Here's the code:

```
def insertion_sort(arr)
  length = arr.size
  arr.each_with_index do |number, index|

    current_minimum = arr.last(length - index).min
    current_minimum_index = arr.last(length-index).index(current_minimum) + index # this insure it will delete the right element
    arr.delete_at(current_minimum_index)
    arr.insert(index, current_minimum)

  end
end

arr =  [7, 68, 42, 46, 9, 91, 77, 46, 86, 1]

answer = insertion_sort(arr)
puts "---------------------------------------------------------------"
puts "Finally we get #{answer.to_s}"
```

Comment: Just FYI from your question: 
"> I got a mission to sort this array using selection sort"..

If the assignment was looking for selection sort then you should know that they're looking at your understanding of the selection sort algorithm, and not the code. The code that you wrote is not exactly selection sort. Why is method named `insertion_sort`?

Comment: @ Surya, I am learning ruby, that's part of my homework. As you said, actually my code not match the defining of  [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort), for example it should move the specific element to right position, not to delete it firstly then insert it back to the array. But thank you to mention that.

Comment: Please don't add your final code as an answer unless you intend to select it as the real answer.

Answer (score 0):

To implement a [Selection Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) in Ruby you can use [`Kernel#loop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-loop), being careful to pass `obj` to [`break`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-break+Statement) in order to get the correct return value.

```
arr = [7, 68, 42, 46, 9, 91, 77, 46, 86, 1]

sorted = loop.with_object([]) do |_,obj|
  mindex = arr.index arr.min                     #find index of a minimum
  obj << arr.delete_at(mindex)                   #push this minimum value to obj
  break obj if arr.empty?
end

sorted #=> [1, 7, 9, 42, 46, 46, 68, 77, 86, 91]
```

See [`with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) for more info.

Comment: I tried your code. The `obj` is started as an empty array. Every time it gets a minimal element's index from `arr`,  delete it ,  then push it to the new array `obj`.When the last element in `arr` is deleted, the loop finish. This way creates a new array rather than sorting an array. But still thanks for your help . @sagarpandya82

Comment: @Caven Thanks for taking the time to follow my code. Unfortunately I misunderstood the definition of a selection sort hence my code.

Comment: @ sagarpandya82  It's ok, the mission's purpose was not to understand selection sort. It just wanted me to have a better understanding about array.